# How to observe changes in pure Swift object bridged to NSObject?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a Space class written in pure Swift. And I need to use it in AppKit environment. I try to build controller to get/set data from Space to interface and back. First I made SpaceController, where I defined var `_space` as a `Space<SomeClass, Double>` (OK) and variable `axes` which takes and sets value inside `_space.axes`

```
    @objc var axes:[Any] {
        defer { Swift.print ("will return \(_space?.axes ?? [])") }
        return _space?.axes  ?? []
    }

    @objc func setAxes(_ axes:[Any]) {
        if let axes = axes as? [Axis<Double>] {
            _space?.axes = axes
        }
    }
```

Problem appears when I try to observe changes.
If I put `willChange..` or `didChange...` anywhere (in this case in setting `_space`)

```
    var _space: Space<SomeClass, Double>? = nil {

        willSet {
            willChangeValue(for: \SpaceController.axes)
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(for: \SpaceController.axes)
        }
    }
```

i got an error:

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x60c000067ac0 of class '_TtGC5Space4AxisSd_' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[_TtGC5Space4AxisSd_ addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:]
2018-07-31 17:37:37.780765+0200 SpaceView[33012:2077391] Unrecognized selector -[_TtGC5Space4AxisSd_ addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:]
```

How I can observe changes in Space.axes array?

Comment: Does `Space` conform to `NSKeyValueObserving` or is `Space` a subclass of `NSObject` (which provides an implementation of `NSKeyValueObserving`)?

Comment: Nope. Space isn’t subclass of NSObject and doesn’t conform to NSKeyValueObserving. But thank you for hint. Do you think it’s enough to implement protocol?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a Swift expert. `methodSignatureForSelector:` is a method of `NSObject`.

Comment: "@objc is not supported within extensions of generic classes or classes that inherit from generic classes" — I think it will not work.